# Counting common elements in arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have two objects:

```json
obj1 [
 'Anime',
 'Movies/TV Series',
 'Coding',
 'Cooking',
 'Sport/Fitness',
 'Gaming'
]
```

and

```json
obj 2 [
 'Music',
 'Movies/TV Series',
 'Coding',
 'Party/Night Clubs',
 'Gaming',
 'Traveling',
 'Roleplay'
]
```

I need to count the number of common elements in arrays.
How can I do it in `javascript`?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a filter with includes:

```js
var a=[
  'Anime',
  'Movies/TV Series',
  'Coding',
  'Cooking',
  'Sport/Fitness',
  'Gaming'
],b=[
  'Music',
  'Movies/TV Series',
  'Coding',
  'Party/Night Clubs',
  'Gaming',
  'Traveling',
  'Roleplay'
];
console.log(a.filter(e=>b.includes(e)).length);
```